# R: subset dataframe for all rows after a condition is met

Tags: r, dplyr, subset

So I'm having a dataset of the following form:

```
ID    Var1   Var2
1      2      0
1      8      0
1      12     0
1      11     1
1      10     1
2      5      0
2      8      0
2      7      0
2      6      1
2      5      1
```

I would like to subset the dataframe and create a new dataframe, containing only the rows after Var1 first reached its group-maximum (including the row this happens) up to the row where Var2 becomes 1 for the first time (also including this row). So what I'd like to have should look like this:

```
ID    Var1   Var2
1      12     0
1      11     1
2      8      0
2      7      0
2      6      1
```

The original dataset contains a number of NAs and the function should simply ignore those. Also if Var2 never reaches "1" for a group is should just add all rows to the new dataframe (of course only the ones after Var1 reaches its group maximum).
However I cannot wrap my hand around the programming. Does anyone know help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `dplyr` solution with `cumsum` based `filter` will do what the question asks for.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(cumsum(Var1 == max(Var1)) == 1, cumsum(Var2) <= 1)
## A tibble: 5 x 3
## Groups:   ID [2]
#     ID  Var1  Var2
#  <int> <int> <int>
#1     1    12     0
#2     1    11     1
#3     2     8     0
#4     2     7     0
#5     2     6     1
```

**Edit**

Here is a solution that tries to answer to the OP's comment and question edit.

```
df1 %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with('Var')), ~replace_na(., 0L)) %>%
  filter(cumsum(Var1 == max(Var1)) == 1, cumsum(Var2) <= 1)
```

**Data**

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "
ID    Var1   Var2
1      2      0
1      8      0
1      12     0
1      11     1
1      10     1
2      5      0
2      8      0
2      7      0
2      6      1
2      5      1
", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. However this doesn't work 100% right on the actual dataset. For most groups only one row remains, which can't be. How does the solution deal with NAs and if there is no "1" in Var2? I just edited the question to make this clearer

Comment: @philipp.kn_98 See if the solution in the edit answers the question.

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table` with `.I`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[df1[, .I[cumsum(Var1 == max(Var1)) & cumsum(Var2) <= 1], by="ID"]$V1]
#   ID Var1 Var2
#1:  1   12    0
#2:  1   11    1
#3:  2    8    0
#4:  2    7    0
#5:  2    6    1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
    Var1 = c(2L, 8L, 12L, 11L, 10L, 5L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 5L), Var2 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame",
    row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is `data.table` translation of Rui Barradas' working solution:

```r
library(data.table)

dat <- fread(text = "
ID    Var1   Var2
1      2      0
1      8      0
1      12     0
1      11     1
1      10     1
2      5      0
2      8      0
2      7      0
2      6      1
2      5      1
", header = TRUE)

dat[, .SD[cumsum(Var1 == max(Var1)) & cumsum(Var2) <= 1], by="ID"]
```